# Converting data error in generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, nodes

I have this generic node class:

```
class Node<E>
    {
        private E data;
        private Node<E> link;

        public Node(E d)
        {
            data = d;
            link = null;
        }

        public Node(E d, Node<E> l)
        {
            data = d;
            link = l;
        }

        public void AddNodeAfter(E d)
        {
            link = new Node<E>(d, link);
        }
    }
```

And I have my main class with two lines:

```
Node<int> n1 = new Node<int>(100);
n1.AddNodeAfter(4.4); //error here
```

The line `n1.AddNodeAfter(4.4)` is giving me the error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'` which I don't entirely understand.

As far as I know, the last node contains an `int` as its `data` but the node is generic, so I'm assuming it doesn't matter what the next node is since `data` can change from node to node.

But clearly I'm missing something. So my question is why am I getting this converting error in the generic class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not missing anything. you defined your generic type as `int` and you are passing `double` to `AddAfterNode` method

Your method will become as:

```
 public void AddNodeAfter(int d)
 {
     link = new Node<int>(d, link);
 }
```

So you can not pass anything other than `int`

If you want the code to work just change `int` to `object`.

Also there is better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are used to create a sort of "template" for a class, a way to parameterize the specific types used by the class. `Node<int>` in essence creates a new class based on `Node<E>` where all `E`'s are substituted with `int`, so the type of `link` is `Node<int>` for your `n1` instance. You are free to create `Node<double>` instances as well, you just can't link them together based on your type definition.

If you want to truly house *any* type of object in your nodes, you'll need to have a more flexible type, like `Object` for your node data and use something like reflection if you need to get at the type of the data.

Answer (score 1):

`Node<E>` is a generic class there's no concept of generic object. `new Node<int>()` is typed object with integer. It can only accept type which can be implicitly converted to integer.

see the [Implicit Conversions on the Predefined Types](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1997935&seqNum=7).